# Why do IBOutlets only respond to one of the multiple view controllers?

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller, iboutlet

I have multiple ViewControllers in my storyboard, and I need various objects in the story board to link to vars in my code.

**Screenshot of my ViewControllers**
[image]

I'm only able to ctrl + drag an IBOutlet from the ViewController I initially began with, and changing the story entrance point doesn't affect the problem.

**Code I am trying to link**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view typically from a    nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @objc func didTapButton(_ tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    }
}

extension ViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {

}
```

Comment: Solved the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you specified the correct "Custom Class" for each of your view controllers.

That is, set ViewController as the custom class for each of your view controllers.

Like this:

[image: Correct]

Answer (score 0):

Link the UIView class you want to connect with the UIView in the storyboard.